# 3D stacked bars in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot multiple stacked bar in only one `'detached'` bar plot. E.g, imagine this exactly [bar](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3_detached.png) plot, but stacked, instead of one single color.

[image]

Comment: You mean as in the first image?

Comment: You seem to have found the correct command, at what point do you get stuck exactly?

Comment: The last plot: (Create a 3-D bar graph with the style option 'stacked'): I want to add a z-axis and plot this kind of graph repeatedly in each z(i). Am I clear ?

Comment: Not really, at least, not to  me...

Comment: @Junuxx: I think the OP wants to plot multiple stacked bar in only one `'detached'` bar plot. E.g, imagine this exactly [bar plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3_detached.png), but stacked, instead of one single color.

Comment: @Junuxx Exaclty like Victor Hugo said !!

Comment: @user764186 Can you update your question to clarify for new visitors? :-)

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/258015) can help...

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
% Set up two random data sets

data1=rand(10);
data2=rand(10);

% plot the first data set

bh=bar3(data1);

% Loop through each row and shift bars upwards

for i=1:length(bh)
      zz = get(bh(i),'Zdata');
      k = 1;

      % Bars are defined by 6 faces(?), adding values from data2 will
      % shift the bars upwards accordingly, I'm sure this could be made
      % better!
      for j = 0:6:(6*length(bh)-6)  
             zz(j+1:j+6,:)=zz(j+1:j+6,:)+data2(k,i);
             k=k+1;
      end

      % Reset Zdata in chart
      set(bh(i),'Zdata',zz);
end

% Set face colour to red for data1

set(bh,'FaceColor',[1 0 0]);

% Apply hold so that data2 can be plotted

hold on;

% Plot data2
bh=bar3(data2);

% Set face color to blue

set(bh,'FaceColor',[0 0 1]);
hold off;
```

Comment: Can this be done with either Python or R or even Excel?