# Matlab: 3D stacked bar chart

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d, stacked

I'm trying to create a 3D stacked bar chart as in this question: [3D stacked bars in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156133/3d-stacked-bars-in-matlab]). However unlike that question I want to use 3 datasets instead of 2. I think I have a (probably simple) problem where the bars don't shift up correctly or something similar.

The three datasets I have are called test1, test2 and test3 and are respectively:

```
5 10 7
1 100 0
1 3 2

10 15 10
10 80 10
5 5 15

10 10 10
20 200 20
30 10 30
```

And plotting them produces this:
[image: Stacked bar chart where stacks don't shift up correctly]

As you can see the central bar should add up to 380 but is only 280 tall. The bars for one of the datasets seem to be rendered "inside" the other two datasets, which would also explain why the bars have 3 central separation lines instead of the 2 we'd expect.

The code I'm using is:

```
core=bar3(test1);
set(core,'FaceColor',[1 0 0]); %red

for i=1:length(core)
    zz=get(core(i),'Zdata');
        k=1;
        for j= 0:6:(6*length(core)-6)
            zz(j+1:j+6,:)=zz(j+1:j+6,:)+test2(k,i);
            k=k+1;
        end
    set(core(i),'Zdata',zz);
end

hold on

core=bar3(test2);

set(core,'FaceColor',[0 1 1]);%cyan
hold off

for i=1:length(core)
    zz=get(core(i),'Zdata');
    k=1;
    for j= 0:6:(6*length(core)-6)
        zz(j+1:j+6,:)=zz(j+1:j+6,:)+test3(k,i);
        k=k+1;
    end
    set(core(i),'Zdata',zz);
end


hold on
core=bar3(test3);
set(core,'FaceColor',[1 1 0]);%yellow
hold off
```

How do I make the bars shift up properly? Or alternatively, how can I use Matlab code to make a 3D stacked bar chart for the data? Any help greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loops use:

```
 zz(j+1:j+6,:)=zz(j+1:j+6,:)+test2(k,i)+test3(k,i);
```

instead of `zz(j+1:j+6,:)=zz(j+1:j+6,:)+test2(k,i);`.

Or you can use the same string in the second loops.